# how do i use ternary operator to add selected attribute in pug

Tags: pug

how do i use ternary operator to add selected attribute in pug

```
select#selectProductSort.selectProductSort.form-control
        option(value='') --
        option(value='Jan',(selection =='Jan') ? 'selected': '') Jan
        option(value='Feb') Feb
        option(value='Mar') Mar
        option(value='Apr') Apr
        option(value='May') May
        option(value='Jun') Jun
        option(value='Jul') Jul
        option(value='Aug') Aug
        option(value='Sep') Sep
        option(value='Oct') Oct
        option(value='Nov') Nov
        option(value='Dec') Dec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the attribute assignment wrongly in your pug syntax. You need to define the attribute, and then set its value based on condition.

It will simply be:

```
option(value='Jan', selected=selection == 'Jan') Jan
```