# Pug select default value from loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
   select(name='key', id='key') 
     each skill in ['C', 'C#', 'D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A','A#','B']
        - var selectMe = skill == 'D#'
        if skill == selectMe
          option(value= skill, selected= selectMe)
        else  
          option=skill
```

This is my code so far. I'm trying to select D# as the default but it starts at C. I've tried using a ternary and no loop in the select as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204554/how-do-i-use-ternary-operator-to-add-selected-attribute-in-pug). I realize i'm assigning `true` to selected but I also tried assigning nothing and doing `if selectMe option(value= skill, selected= 'D#'` but no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `selectMe` to be a boolean—either `true` or `false`. Then you check to see if it's equal to `skill`, which will be a string representing a key, so that will never evaluate to `true`.

Instead, try something like this, which sets the value of `selected` to `true` or `false` based on if `skill` is `D#`:

```
select(name='key', id='key') 
  each skill in ['C', 'C#', 'D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A','A#','B']
    option(value= skill, selected= skill === 'D#')= skill
```